# Rename file names from file1..file1000 to file1001...file2000 using python

Tags: python, linux, unix, file-rename

I found it difficult to rename the files. I have a scenario where I have to change a thousand files from filenames `file1..file1000` to `file1001..file2000`. I am using Linux OS and trying to change file names using a python `for` loop. I could concatenate the file names using the command below, but couldn't change the file names sequentially.

```sh
for i in file*; do mv -i "${i}" "${i/file/file100}" ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `shutil.move()`:

```py
import shutil

for i in range(1, 1001):
    shutil.move("file{}".format(i), "file{}".format(1000 + i))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Below is the error.                                                          
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    for i in range(len(files)):
NameError: name 'files' is not defined

Comment: @Akki I updated the answer. The for loop now loops over integers

Comment: Solved! Thanks a lot vinzee

Comment: Vinzee, Just asking. Is there any other alternative to do the same job without import any libraries? like using bash script?

Comment: `shutil` (like `os`) are built-in libraries: there is no need to install anything

Answer (score 0):

Or just stick with `bash` and use the same logic:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do mv file${i} file$(( $i + 1000 )); done
```